# Wix - Remove files only when uninstall, when having REP after InstallInitialize

Tags: wix

I have to accomplish the following: when the product gets completelly uninstalled (from add/remove programs, *not* during an update) I need to specifically delete 2 additional files.

For that I have the following code:

```
<Component Id="RemoveLogosFile" Guid="PUT_MY_GUID" >
  <RemoveFile Id="RemoveLogosFile" Name="MyLogo.jpg" On="uninstall"/>
  <RemoveFile Id="RemoveBundleFile" Name="bundle" On="uninstall"/>
  <Condition>(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (REMOVE=ALL)</Condition>
</Component>
```

The above code works as expected *if*:

```
<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallFinalize"/>
```

meaning the 2 files are deleted *only* during an uninstall from 
add/remove programs and they *don't* get deleted during an update.

But in my installer I have:

```
<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>
```

and the behavior in this case is that the 2 files are *always* deleted regardless if it's an update or removal from add/remove programs.

Can somebody help me accomplish the deletion of those files only when uninstalling from add/remove programs and not during an update, when having

```
<RemoveExistingProducts After="InstallInitialize"/>
```

?

Thank you,
MeCoco

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer. Look here:
http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg42579.html